# What formula to use to isolate d in the following inequation?

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic

I have the following inequation:

$$a > d^k - (d-1)^k + 2k$$

with $a, d, k \in \mathbb{N}$.

What I want is to express this inequation from the point of view of variable $d$, not $a$.

My first intent was to put $2k$ with a:

$$a - 2k > d^k - (d-1)^k$$

Then I wanted to use logarithmic formula to get rid of exponents:

$$log(a - 2k) > log(d^k - (d-1)^k)$$

But it brings more complexity with it:

$$log(a - 2k) > log(d^k) + log(1 - \frac{(div-1)^k}{div^k})$$

What other formula should I consider to reach my goal ?

Comment: For general $k$, there is no way to solve for $d$ (as a closed form expression).

Comment: I forgot to specify, but all variables are restricted to the natural set.